# tkinter fullscreen still available after root.resizable(False,False)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a python application that requires disabling window resize and fullscreen. I tried root.resizable(False, False). It does stop the window from resizing, but for disabling fullscreen, it only works if you minimize it first and then unminimize it. I wonder why and is there a workaround?

Comment: How do you disable the fullscreen mode? Are you under  MS-Windows?

Comment: @Thingamabobs root.resizable(False,False) turning off the window resize for both dimensions also disables the fullscreen mode, you will see a grey button on the original place where the fullscreen button should be.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Also I am under MacOS.

Comment: note that `root.withdraw` isnt the same as `root.iconify`, even if it appears so. Try `iconify` instead, it should work to update the window style.

Comment: you also would have made sure that the window appears in the first place. You could call `root.update_idletasks()` before iconfy for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [tk documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/wm.html#M68), this is probably a bug in the window manager. Keep in mind that `resizable` is a [wm command](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/wm.html#M59).

> Most existing window managers appear to have bugs that affect the operation of the **wm** command. For example, some changes will not take effect if the window is already active: the window will have to be withdrawn and de-iconified in order to make the change happen.